# Playing a video using HTML5/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-controls, html5-video

My HTML5 video code:

```
<video id="myVideo">
<source src="Some source" type="some type" \>
</video>
```

My play button click function:

```
$("#myVideo").play();
```

The code is not working for me. I checked the code with default browser controls for video - Its working fine. The only problem is when i try to make a custom control play button.

Comment: try with [this](http://videojs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$('#myVideo').get(0).play();` instead.

Not that you even need to use jQuery to do so:

```
document.getElementById('myVideo').play();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use HTML either via autoplay or after a button is clicked using the .click() method. as the user above mentioned, you can use #myVideo which can also give you the ability to format and position the video in css.. as shown below:

```
#myVideo {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
top : auto;
display: block;
width: 50%;
}
```